# Manual translation button disappearing

Tags: modern-experience, language

I am trying to translate pages for our SharePoint site. Everytime I refresh the page, the Translate button appears briefly for a fraction of a second, then disappears.

[image: translation button disappearing upon refresh]

I have gone in the **site settings** and then the **language settings** to ensure that the **Enable translation into multiple languages** option is turned on. I also ensured that I added myself in the list of translators.

Nevertheless, I still come across the same issue.

I have been able to work around this by inspecting the menu element in my browser.

[image: inspecting the menu shows that the style display is set to none for this element]

When I change the style display from none to true, the button reappears and I can click on it and begin translating. However, I would rather not having to show this workaround to my colleagues, I'd prefer if the button was simply displayed in the first place!

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have edit or higher permissions on site? You added yourself as a translator for all other languages than English, right?

Comment: Hi @GaneshSanap, sorry I was off for the holidays. Yes I am the site owner and I added myself as a translator. I was actually able to translate the page using the workaround mentioned above (by forcing the button to display by editing the CSS)